# Angular.js http.post request 404 with flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

im getting a bad request, here is my url code:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    print(request)
    user = models.User.get(models.User.email**request.form['email'])
    if request.form['password'] == user.rpe:
        login_user(user)
        return jsonify(user.to_json())
```

here is my html:

```
 <form id="form">
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" id="email" name="correo">
      <input type="password" placeholder="rpe" id="password" name="password">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Log in</button>
</form>
```

and here is my js code:

```
$scope.submit = function(event){
        var form = $('form');
        var values = {};
        $.each(form.serializeArray(), function(i, field){
            values[field.name] = field.value;
        });
        data = JSON.stringify(values);
        console.log(data);
        $http.post('/login', values).success(function () {
          alert('success');
        });   
    }
```

after i do the request with the form, here is what i get:

```
<Request 'http://localhost:8000/login' [POST]>
```

im guessing that this request isnt what it is suppoused to be, im also asking because in other questions some user added a csrf token but i actually dont know how to add one with javascript since im adding my angular app this way:

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return make_response(open('templates/index.html').read())
```

thanks

Comment: What other output do you get from flask? It seems a problem on the python code ... Try accessing the url directly (with `curl`, for example) and see what you get ...

Comment: this is what i get 

curl --data '{"correo":"gilda.beltran@cfe.gob.mx","password":"9B0RN"}' http://localhost:8000/iniciar_sesion
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>

Comment: It looks like your server is expecting `{"email":"<email>", "password":"<password>"}` but you have email named "correo" in the from. Can you change the `name="correo"` to `name="email"` in the form (or make the change server-side to accept correo instead of email)?

Comment: Alright i already made this change before and the problem still is the csrf token missing